# $: command not found error

Tags: bashrc

on opening terminal it shows on top

```
$: command not found
$: command not found
$: command not found
yogesh@yogesh-WNB8PHF4710C-0030:~$
```

and my .bashrc file has

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

Comment: I don't think the problem is from your `.bashrc` file. 2) Try to rename it to something else (`mv ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc.old`), do you still see the issue? 2) Try as a different user, does the other user also have this problem? In the meantime, you could show us the contents of `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_login`, `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

Comment: probably you have quoting issue with your alias for `alert`

Comment: mv ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc.old   worked thank you. what is it mean that making like so $:cmd not fnd before.

Comment: OK, in that case the problem is indeed your `.bashrc`. Strange, I loaded it but didn't have an issue.

Comment: I don't understand. I can't reproduce the problem. This means that the issue is not actually in `~/.bashrc`. However, if it goes away when you rename it, it must be in one of the files loaded by `~/.bashrc`. Please [edit] your question and add the contents of `~/.bash_aliases` and, just in case, of `/etc/bash_completion` and ` /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, add the information and use the [formatting tools](http://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) to make it look clean. I don't understand what your comment means. Also, remember to ping me by adding `@terdon` to your comments or I won't be notified.

Comment: Try `bash -x .bashrc`

Comment: i tried adding echo erro1, 2 ,3  ..... in ~/.bashrc then i got to know error is comming in between                                                                                                         >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

Comment: if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

Comment: @YogeshkumarGN OK, so please edit the contents of `~/.bash_aliases` into your question.

Comment: ~/.bash_aliases is empty

Answer (score 2):

This is not a full-fledged answer. I would post a comment but this is too wordy to fit.

In a comment, you mentioned you put echos into your .bashrc to figure out where the problem was. If I understand correctly, you had something like this:

```
echo 1
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
echo 2
```

And for the output, you got

```
1
$: command not found
$: command not found
$: command not found
2
yogesh@yogesh-WNB8PHF4710C-0030:~$
```

If that's correct, run this command in terminal, and edit the output into your question.

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
  echo "~/.bash_aliases exists."
  echo
  ls -l ~/.bash_aliases
  echo 
  cat ~/.bash_aliases
  echo
  source ~/.bash_aliases
else
  echo "~/.bash_aliases does not exist."
fi
```

Comment: yes exactly i did like you saying, now made Comment line for ~/.bash_aliases. means not using ,i dont know that is it need or not, as am new to ubuntu.

Comment: @YogeshkumarGN You don't need to use that section of the .bashrc, so it's fine if you comment it out. Are you still experiencing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

One cause of this could be "dos" ends of line or this:

"#: command not found"

a) open ~.bashrc in Krusader

b) In Krusader's menu Extras switch on: "Add Byte Order Mark (BOM)"

c) write "#" on the first line of .bashrc file

d) save file

e) run ctrl+alt+T - lxterminal

f) you will get:

#: Befehl nicht gefunden.

or

#: Command not found

if you put "echo" on the first line of .bashrc file, then you get:

"Der Befehl »echo« wurde nicht gefunden, meinten Sie vielleicht:

Befehl »aecho« aus dem Paket »netatalk« (universe)

Befehl »echo« aus dem Paket »coreutils« (main)

echo: Befehl nicht gefunden."

and so on.

If you switch off in Krusader's menu Extras: "Add Byte Order Mark (BOM)"

Then put "#" or "echo" on the first line of the the file ".bashrc"

The error "#: command not found" has disappeared.

So take care that you have switched off "Add Byte Order Mark (BOM)"